# create color map blue scale

Tags: matlab, matrix, color-mapping

Hello I have a matrix

```
A=[
1 1 1;
1 1 2;
1 1 3;
1 2 1;
1 2 2;
1 2 3;
2 1 1;
2 1 2;
2 1 3;
2 2 1;
2 2 2;
2 2 3]
```

containing the Cartesian Product of the elements of the vectors `V1 = [1 2], V2 = [1 2], V3 =[1 2 3]`
In particular each row of the matrix `A` is a combination of the elements of `V1 V2 V3`

Now I would like to create a color map in blue scale where the very light blue correspond to the 1st row `[1 1 1]` and the very dark blue correspond to the 12th row `[2 2 3]`.

My questons:

1) How do I order the intermediate rows in a smart way such as they take intermediate blues? (summing over the rows?)

2) How can I create such blue color map?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How would it have 18 rows?

Comment: it is the Cartesian Product

Comment: By `"intermediate rows"`, do you mean the average of first six and last six rows of A?

Comment: I mean that it would be obvious to consider the first and the last as the lowest value and the highest value....then I should find a logic to order the other rows...it s a bit like the medals during the olimpic games...but here all the 3 medals (1st,2nd,3rd col.) should have the same weight..

Comment: Alright, so you would re-order the rows. But, you have 12 rows in A, then where did that mention of `18 rows` come from?

Comment: Very sorry...it s a typo!!! :(

Comment: So, do the columns correspond to R, G, B respectively? If so, how about `sortrows(A,3)`?

Comment: To be precise the columns represent Duration, Temperature, Intensity. 1 = Low, 3 = High. so the 1st row means low duration, low temperature and low intensity. the last row means medium duration medium temperature high intensity. I want to map these combination to a color map

Comment: sortrows(A,3) means that I want to order according to the 3rd col isn't it? in my case 1 1 2 and 2 1 1 should have the same colour. That's way I thought to sum over the columns and order according to this sum

Comment: See if you meant it the way posted solution deals with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
[sorted_sumcols,idx] = sort(sum(A,2)) %// sum over columns and sort based on the sum
Aout = A(idx,:) %// Aout holds the re-ordered rows of A
```

Output -

```
Aout =
     1     1     1
     1     1     2
     1     2     1
     2     1     1
     1     1     3
     1     2     2
     2     1     2
     2     2     1
     1     2     3
     2     1     3
     2     2     2
     2     2     3
```

For verification, you can look at the values of

```
sorted_sumcols =
     3
     4
     4
     4
     5
     5
     5
     5
     6
     6
     6
     7
```

So, that `[1 1 2]` belongs to the same group of `[2 1 1]`, as both of their `sorted_sumcols` values are `4`  at their row numbers `2` and `4`.

---

### Edit

This section of code extends the earlier code to keep same intensity (column-3) for same group elements -

```
[~,~,ID] = unique(sorted_sumcols) %// IDs for each group
meanvals = accumarray(ID,Aout(:,3),[],@mean) %// mean values for each group
Aout(:,3) = meanvals(ID) %// replicate the mean values to each element
out = Aout./max(Aout(:)) %// finally divide by max of all elements to keep 
                             %//it in [0 1] as needed for custom colormaps
```

Output -

```
>> Aout
Aout =
                         1                         1                         1
                         1                         1          1.33333333333333
                         1                         2          1.33333333333333
                         2                         1          1.33333333333333
                         1                         1                         2
                         1                         2                         2
                         2                         1                         2
                         2                         2                         2
                         1                         2          2.66666666666667
                         2                         1          2.66666666666667
                         2                         2          2.66666666666667
                         2                         2                         3

>> out
out =
         0.333333333333333         0.333333333333333         0.333333333333333
         0.333333333333333         0.333333333333333         0.444444444444444
         0.333333333333333         0.666666666666667         0.444444444444444
         0.666666666666667         0.333333333333333         0.444444444444444
         0.333333333333333         0.333333333333333         0.666666666666667
         0.333333333333333         0.666666666666667         0.666666666666667
         0.666666666666667         0.333333333333333         0.666666666666667
         0.666666666666667         0.666666666666667         0.666666666666667
         0.333333333333333         0.666666666666667         0.888888888888889
         0.666666666666667         0.333333333333333         0.888888888888889
         0.666666666666667         0.666666666666667         0.888888888888889
         0.666666666666667         0.666666666666667                         1
```

Comment: yes now how can I create a blue colormap from sorted_sumcols?

Comment: @gabboshow How about `colormap(Aout./3)`? Custom colormaps need to be in the range `[0 1]`, so this division must take care of it.

Comment: but like this row 2 and row 3 will have 2 different colors isn't it?

Comment: @gabboshow Well I assumed all three to have the same weights, as you mentioned in the comments to the question. But, if they don't, then you need to need to define "color" with respect to these three parameters.

Comment: what I mean is that according to sorted_sumcols row 2 and row 3 should have the same color (their sum is 4). colormap(Aout./3) will assign a different color to row 2 and row 3 of A...

Comment: @gabboshow You mean ..`will assign a different color to row 2 and row 3 of Aout`, right?